# required field not working inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Am trying to implement default required field into HTML5 form but it is not working if I have it inside a div.

Not working code:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-phone">
      <label for="phone" id="lphone">Phone no:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone-Number" required/><br> 
    </div>
    <div id="confirmDetails">
        <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Call Me!" />
     </div>
 </form>
```

Working code:

```js
$('#confirmDetails').on('click', 'input', function(e) {
  alert(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-phone">
    <label for="phone" id="lphone">Phone no:</label><br>

    <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone-Number" required/><br>
  </div>
  <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Call Me!" />
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean not working?

Comment: `#confirmDetails` button does not submit the form whereas `#submitbtn` button does. [The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before **submitting** the form.](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: @Anandhunadesh: validation is not happening. it directly goes to function

Comment: @Mikey but even if I remove the div it doesnt take validtion 
$('#submitbtns').on('click', function (e) {
alert(test);
}

Comment: @raulxbox It works just fine....see this  https://jsfiddle.net/uyg6tj5q/

Comment: 1) you don't have a `#submitbtns` button but `#submitbtn`. 2) you should be listening to the form's `onsubmit` event i.e. `$('form').on('submit', function (e) {`

Comment: think you are missing a paren.   https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/75/

Comment: @Anandhunadesh yes but if you add onclick to this id it doesn't

Comment: @raulxbox don't add event for div. add event for the button

Comment: @BryanDellinger in your fiddle it goes to function but doesn't validate. I mean required field is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an id to the form:

```
<form id="myForm">
<div class="form-phone">
      <label for="phone" id="lphone">Phone no:</label><br>

      <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone-Number" required/><br> 
 </div>
<div id="confirmDetails">
     <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Call Me!" />
     </div>
 </form>
```

And listen for the event "submit" of the form:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit',function (e) {
  alert(test);
})
```

This way you leave the navigator to make the validation. And don't forget to add validation on the server side

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes sir!! this is what I was looking for.. will select as an answer after 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong logic with js.
Add click event to the submit button, not the div

use this

```
$('#submitbtn').on('click', 'input',function (e) {
alert(test);
})
```